# Security Token Signature Key Not Found Exception IDX10501 Unable to match key kid

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, azure-active-directory, certificate, blazor

I have a blazor app generated by VS 2019 and the auto-generated Azure AD Authentication. The authentication worked just fine until I started playing with the `web server setting`s in the `projects settings > debug` tab.

[image]

Then when starting the debugger, VS asked me to generate a certificate and trust it. I clicked Yes (do not have the screenshot of the prompt). Since then, I get the error from the title.

[image]

Any advice what to do to avoid this error? I have seen this posted many times but all the advices are related to the AD setup and there is nothing really change to that in my case. The solution itself is **running just fine on another machine** and I copied it over from it.

[image]

Comment: What things changed for your web server setting ?

Comment: I just tried to untick the Enable SSL and Enable Anonymous Authentication and tick Enable Windows Auhtnetication. Then I switched it back.

Comment: Sorry , not reproduce by repeating your operations , but you can check the statup , whether it changed after the operations ?

Comment: That is really the problem because I cannot locate any changes. Moreover, I copied the project over from the machine where it works with the same result so I believe it must be related to the generated certificates.